# How can I select an element in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I'm a beginner in this programming language. I beg your pardon.

How can I select an element in JQuery?  What is wrong with my code? SOmeone help me.

---

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
         <head>
         <title></title>
         <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
         </head>
    <body>
    <input type="password">

    <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function(){

         $('input[type=password]').attr({
              name: 'pass'
              style: [
                  color: 'blue',
                  font-size: '20px'
              ],
            });
        )};
    </script>
```

Comment: What isn't working?

Comment: The problem is not in the selector, but `font-size` which is a syntax error. [Keep the browser's error console open](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-do-i-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers) so that you see the error messages.

Comment: typo : at last line of document ready close  )};

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use .css() for style property

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('input[type=password]').attr({
    name: 'pass'
  }).css({
    "color": "blue",
    "font-size": "20px"
  });

});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="password">
```

Comment: Thank you mister! Can I use jQuery Method Chaining in this?

Comment: yeah you can able to use @Fawkes

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you meant to write:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type=password]').attr({
    name: 'pass',
    style: 'color: blue; font-size: 20px'
  });
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="password">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
                 <head>
                 <title></title>
                 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
                 </head>
            <body>
            <input type="password">

            <script type="text/javascript">
                 $(document).ready(function(){

                 $('input[type=password]').attr("name","pass").css({"color":"blue","font-size":"20px"});
               });
            </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Always use single line if it is possible